# Windows 7 & kodak printer esp 7

Tags: windows-7, printer

I have bought a new PC with Windows 7 and a Kodak wireless printer esp 7.  I can't download the software always unsuccessful and can't connect to my printer.  Any suggestions?

**Edit** (from the other, duplicate question):

Still having problems with printing. I did get it working by removing 'bonjour' but turned on yesterday and hey presto it's not working again. The printer is installed and showing as disconnected. Any ideas now?

The chat doesn't work with Windows 7, I have downloaded the latest version, they take ages to answer emails, need to print stuff urgently. It's driving me insane!! Please help.

Answer (score 2):

See this page : [ESP 7 All-in-One Printer Software, Driver & Firmware Downloads](http://www.kodak.com/global/mul/service/downloads/DownloadLookup.jhtml?pq-path=13660&product=EKN035329&operatingSystem=windows_7).

Windows 7 drivers are to be found in the drop-down list, dating from 15 September, 2009.
This contains drivers and firmware, but don't do the later without taking precautions.

Comment: Yoraf, it's customary in this case to upvote the question and mark it as the answer ...

Comment: He can't upvote, he only has 3 points. He needs more than 15 points to upvote.

Comment: Alex, he should still mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

for the answer to your ESP7 question please go to [www.kodak.com/go/aiosupport](http://www.kodak.com/go/aiosupport).
There is also chat help available 24/7.

Comment: Ricky, thanks but the chat isn't enabled for windows 7.   I did get it working by removing 'bonjour' but turned on yesterday and hey presto it's not working again.  The printer is installed and showing as disconnected.  Any ideas now?